# how to open a large bin file ( ~ 8 GB image stream) in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

**Background**

The binary file contain successive raw output from a camera sensor which is in the form of a bayer pattern. i.e. the data is successive blocks containing information of the form shown below and where each block is a image in image stream

`[(bayer width) * (bayer height) * sizeof(short)]`

**Objective**

To read information from a specific block of data and store it  as an array for processing. I was digging through the opencv documentation, and totally lost on how to proceed. I apologize for the novice question but any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can read the binary file (as a whole), I would try to use
[Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) to read it into a `numpy.array`. You can use [numpy.fromstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) and depending on the system the file was written on (little or big endian), use `>i2` or `<i2` as your data type (you can find the list of data types [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype)).

Also note that > means big endian and < means little endian (more on that [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.byteswapping.html))

You can set an offset and specify the length in order to read to read a certain block.

```
import numpy as np

with open('datafile.bin','r') as f:
    dataBytes = f.read()

data = np.fromstring(dataBytes[blockStartIndex:blockEndIndex], dtype='>i2')
```

In case you cannot read the file as a whole, I would use [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (requires a little knowledge of C) in order to break it down to multiple files and then use the method above.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, with @lsxliron's suggestion I looked into using Numpy to achieve my goals and this is what I ended up doing

```
import numpy as np

# Data read length
length = (bayer width) * (bayer height)
# In terms of bytes: short = 2
step = 2 * length
# Open filename
img = open("filename","rb")
# Block we are interested in i
img.seek(i * step) 
# Copy data as Numpy array
Bayer = np.fromfime(img,dtype=np.uint16,count=length)
```

Bayer now holds the bayer pattern values in the form of an numpy array success!!